# Error "MachineToApplication" when open solution with VS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

Few years ago (2005), a colleague created a VS2005 project an "Web Application" and not a "Web site". Now I have to do some change

When I open the solution, I get this error :

*It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.*

I'd like use the Visual Studio web server.  How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks,

Update 1 : (web.config localisation)
http://i54.tinypic.com/2vtw7xk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm that your web.config file is in the root directory.

Comment: As per your screen shot it is not in root directory. it is inside the 'code' folder.

Comment: you are right, was not in the root of the solution. Not possible to convert an ASP.NET Application to Web Site ?

Comment: Kris, is your problem solved? Can you please explain what you want to do exactly?